# Matlab: Using interp2 in ode45

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 2-dimensional matrix with discrete values and I want to use the ode45 command.
To do this I used interp2 to create a function ode45 can use.

The problem is, it looks like ode45 is moving out of my defined area and so interp2 returns NaN-values. To get rid of the NaN I used an extrapolation value but now it seems that ode45 integrates from my initial values to this extrapolation value, disregarding any of my given values in the matrix.

Here is a little example with a 2x2 matrix:

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;

A = rand(2, 2);              % the matrix with my values
x = 1:2;         
y = x;
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y);     % grid on which my values are defined
xi = 1:0.5:2;              
yi = xi;
[Xi, Yi] = meshgrid(xi, yi); % interpolation grid

tspan = 0:0.2:1;

B = @(xq,yq)interp2(X, Y, A, xq, yq, 'linear', 10);   % interpolation function with extrapval of 10

[T,C] = ode45(@(Xi,Yi)B(Xi,Yi), tspan, [Xi,Yi]);       % ode45 function using interp-function and intital values [Xi,Yi]
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: You're passing a constant matrix to `ode45` as the first input. I think you mean to call it as `[T,C] = ode45(B, tspan, [Xi,Yi]);` since B contains your function handle.

Comment: When I'm using B instead of @(Xi,Yi)B(Xi,Yi) I'm getting the same results. I'm using Matlab R2010b by the way, don't know if it makes a difference.

Comment: My mistake, you're actually passing a function that is equivalent to just passing `B`. I'm actually not sure what 's going on. There's something odd about what your doing though. If `B` is your ODE and you apparently have two state variables `(Xi,Yi)` I would think `B` needs to return 2 values which correspond to the rates of change of `Xi` and `Yi`. My best guess is that ode45 is reshaping those arrays in a way that doesn't give an error, but isn't what you want.

Comment: Yes, `B(Xi,Yi)` gives me a new matrix with the interpolated values from matrix `A`. I don't know what ODE is doing with it, because I thought it would give me the trajectories depending on my values in `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this will work as you have set it up. Your ODE function `B` should take inputs of time, and a single input (column) vector of state variables and return a column vector of rates of change for the state variables. Please look at the help documentation for `ode45`.

If your state variables are coordinate pairs (x,y), you need to return dx/dt and dy/dt for each pair. I'm not sure how this could come from interpolating on a single array. I think you need something like the following:

```
clear

%// Define the right hand side of your ODE such that
%// dx/dt = Ax(x,y)
%// dy/dt = Ay(x,y)
%// For demonstration I'm using a circular velocity field.
xref = linspace(-pi,pi);
yref = linspace(-pi,pi);
[xref yref] = meshgrid(xref,yref);

r=sqrt(xref.^2+yref.^2);
Ax = [-yref./r];
Ay = [xref./r];

%// Initial states:
xi = 1:0.05:2;
yi = xi;
[Xi, Yi] = meshgrid(xi, yi); % interpolation grid

%// state array = [x1; y1; x2; y2; ... ]
states = [Xi(:)'; Yi(:)'];
states = states(:);

B = @(t,states) reshape([ interp2(xref,yref,Ax,states(1:2:end),states(2:2:end)) ...
                          interp2(xref,yref,Ay,states(1:2:end),states(2:2:end))]',size(states));

tspan=0:.02:10;
[T,C] = ode45(B, tspan, states);

for i=1:size(C,1)
    figure(1)
    clf
    plot(C(i,1:2:end),C(i,2:2:end),'k.')
    axis(pi*[-1 1 -1 1])
    drawnow
end
```

Obviously this code relies heavily on managing array shapes to maintain the correct ordering for x, y, dx/dt, and dy/dt. There may be a simpler way to write it.

**EDIT**
The key here is to clearly define a state vector and define your ODE function to match that state vector. The state vector must be a column vector and your ODE function must return a column vector. In the code above I have chosen to represent the state of the system as a vector formated as `states(:,1) = [x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 ... ]`. That means your ODE must return a column vector of the form

```
[ d/dt(x1) ]
[ d/dt(y1) ]
[ d/dt(x2) ]
[ d/dt(y2) ]
[ d/dt(x2) ]
[ d/dt(y2) ]
[   ...    ]
[   ...    ]
```

You will also require 2 interpolations, 1 for the x components and 1 for the y, to get the rates of change based on `Ax` and `Ay`. The way I chose to do this was with the line

```
B = @(t,states) reshape([ interp2(xref,yref,Ax,states(1:2:end),states(2:2:end)) ...
                          interp2(xref,yref,Ay,states(1:2:end),states(2:2:end))]',size(states));
```

This line is a bit complex and difficult to understand because it is written as an anonymous function. If you define a stand-alone function for this it will be much more clear and could be written as

```
function ODEvals = B(t,states,xref,yref,Ax,Ay)
x(:,1) = states(1:2:end); %// extract x values from states as a column vector
y(:,1) = states(2:2:end); %// extract y values
dxdt(:,1) = interp2(xref,yref,Ax,x,y); %// interpolate Ax
dydt(:,1) = interp2(xref,yref,Ay,x,y); %// interpolate Ay

%// concatenate the results, dxdt and dydt are column vectors
%//  1) put the as column 1 and 2
%//  2) take the transpose so they become rows one and two:
%//         [d/dt(x1)  d/dt(x2) ... ]
%//         [d/dt(y1)  d/dt(y2) ... ]
%//  3) reshape into a single column, the ordering will be:
%//        [ d/dt(x1) ]
%//        [ d/dt(y1) ]
%//        [ d/dt(x2) ]
%//        [ d/dt(y2) ]
%//        [ d/dt(x2) ]
%//        [ d/dt(y2) ]
%//        [   ...    ]
%//        [   ...    ]
ODEvals = reshape([dxdt dydt]',[],1);
```

One last note:
To use `ode45`, your ODE function must take inputs of a time (`t` above) and a state vector, even if you don't use the time. Additional arguments are optional, see the documentation on `ode45` for more details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort! I'm still trying to fully understand your program, but as far as i see it does exactly what I want my program to do. Could you explain in a few words what exactly happens in `B = @(t,states) reshape([ interp2(xref,yref,Ax,states(1:2:end),states(2:2:end)) ...
                          interp2(xref,yref,Ay,states(1:2:end),states(2:2:end))]',size(states));` I don't realy understand what your variable `states()` is doing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I think i got i now.